# Can't click ok on Alert()

Tags: ios, macos, react-native, alert

I've been using react native on windows everything was working good, I recently started to code react native on OSX to be able to see what my apps are working on IOS however since I started I'm getting through a lot a problem I can't fix...
One of them is that when I make an alert on the phone I can't click Ok... I  to refresh the app if I want to close the alert. I can click the alert but I have to wait like 3 minutes it feels like the animation is super slow here :(

Is there something I set up wrong? I don't really understand
I did not really want to use alert as debug but since I can't see my log here as well it gives me no other choice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the animation is slow try doing command+t, it toggles slow animations. Maybe you activated it by mistake

Comment: @auticcat Hello, I think I might have activated that by mistake it is working pretty great right now.

Answer (score 0):

Animations slowing down could be because you have Debug JS Remotely option turned on from developer menu(the one that pops up after shaking the device). But it would be helpful to share the code here to make things clear.

I implemented an error popup in my app and it seems to work great, however it does not have any custom animation.

```
 renderError() {
if (this.props.error) {
  console.log(this.props.error);
  Alert.alert('Error', JSON.stringify(this.props.error), [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    { text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') },
  ]);
}
}
```